# Can not set image src via jquery / javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

I have an image that needs to be set dynamically via jquery or javascript

```
<img id="myImage" src="" />
```

my view called "UserProfile" my controller name is "User" generated url is: https://localhost/Carpool.Web/User/UserProfile

my images located under wwwroot/images folder

Now when i use any of the following i got 404 and the image is not displayed:

```
$("#myImage").attr({ "src": "/wwwroot/images/info.png" }); //console => <img id="myImage" src="https://localhost/Carpool.Web/User/UserProfile/wwwroot/images/info.png">
$("#myImage").attr({ "src": "~/images/info.png" });//console => <img id="myImage" src="~/images/info.png">
$("#myImage").attr({ "src": "/images/info.png" });//console => <img id="myImage" src="https://localhost/Carpool.Web/User/UserProfile/images/info.png">
$("#myImage").attr({ "src": "images/info.png" }); //console => <img id="myImage" src="https://localhost/images/info.png">
document.getElementById("myImage").src // tried all as above
```

If my view is "Index" then i don't have this issue, also site logo can be displayed with no issue
Is this related to my upgrade to asp.net core 3.1?

Comment: Sounds like you have absolute paths to your images. That is why it will work on index and not on other pages if these pages are not on the same level as index. Then you would have to navigate to the correct folder first to get the images.

Comment: Is there is a way to solve this? i don't want to hard code the full path since we have different env's

Comment: `my images located under wwwroot/images folder` Are you sure that the image indeed can not access with *`https://localhost/images/<image_file_name>`*? Please share your project folder structure, so that we can troubleshoot the issue better.

Answer (score 0):

I need to see your tree structure to correct it.

put '.' or '..' in front of the path

For example

"src": "./wwwroot/images/info.png" 
// this is only if when the images folder is have same parent folder with your page

"src": ../wwwroot/images/info.png"